# Trouble understanding absolute value inequality property of integrals

Tags: integration

I am having trouble understanding the following property of definite integrals:

$\big|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \leq \int_a^b|f(x)|dx $

1. What would be an example of where the left hand side is less than the right hand side?
2. Also, I was able to come up with a (seeming) violation of this rule when $a > b$

   $\big|\int_5^2 -4dx|= 42 > \int_5^2|-4|dx = -42 $

   Am I supposed to be assuming that $a < b$ ? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stick to $a<b$. See what happens when $f$ takes negative and positive values.

Comment: It should be $b>a$.

Comment: For 1. Consider $a = 0$, $b=2\pi$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: As a concrete example, $\left| \int_{-1}^1 x\, dx \right| = 0$, $\int_{-1}^1 |x|\,dx = 1$.

Comment: The intuitive reason is that things can cancel out on the right-hand side but not on the left.  e.g., consider $|\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x) \, dx| < \int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(x)|\, dx$.  This is exactly analogous to the fact that $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$, since positives and negatives may cancel out on the left but not on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=x$ on [-1, 1].$$ \big|\int_{-1}^{1} xdx|=0 \le \int_{-1}^{1}|x|dx =1$$

Sketching a graph will be quite helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Why does this seem to only happen when the a is a negative value?

Comment: You can have positive values for $a$ as well. Just shift the graph to the right and you get the same result.